# How to disable security in activemq apollo

Tags: activemq-classic, apollo

I have installed apollo 1.7.1 and using a broker with default setting. When I try to connect to this broker, got this error message.

```
Authentication failed. Credentials=[]
```

By default it comes with file based authentication setup. How can I disable this authentication?

Comment: Apache Apollo is dead / not developed anymore, I would suggest to use regular ActiveMQ or ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: Thank you Claus. I will keep that in mind.